# OnPaint event is always called twice

Tags: c++builder, vcl

I have a simple implementation for the `OnPaint` event in my Borland C++ (Delphi) program. In `OnPaint` in an MDI child, a grid is drawn and inside the grid I show a number of bitmaps.

When I open/create a new Window, this is what happens:

- The window is shown.
- There is an `OnPaint` event, in which I draw the grid and the bitmaps, but some of the bitmaps do not show completely, there are some lines in the window where the part of the bitmap is not shown.
- Then there is a next `OnPaint` event, the same code is called and now all the bitmaps are drawn completely.

Other users of the program report more than 2 `OnPaint` events, with similar failures in the bitmaps.

I included a counter, the counter shows that `OnPaint` is, in my case, always called twice when I create a new window, when the window is redrawn as result of moving, `OnPaint` is only called once. I disabled some of the drawing code to see if something here is causing the second call, but this is not the case.

Is there an explanation for this behavour, and better, a cure ?

```
void __fastcall  TfrmSpoor::FormPaint(TObject *Sender)

{
... do some calculations

    HorzScrollBar->Increment = PixelsPerHokX;
    HorzScrollBar->Range = PixelsPerHokX * Railplan->xGrootte;
    VertScrollBar->Increment = PixelsPerHokY;
    VertScrollBar->Range = PixelsPerHokY * Railplan->yGrootte;

    CanvasOffsetX = (int)-HorzScrollBar->Position % PixelsPerHokX;
    CanvasOffsetY = (int)-VertScrollBar->Position % PixelsPerHokY;

    Canvas->Lock(); // reserveert de Canvas voor deze thread
    OnPaintTeller++;
    Color = temp.GeefSymboolKleur(Vormgeving->SymboolGrootte);

... do some more calculations

    {
        TekenRaster(Canvas, Deelplan);
        TekenRailplan(Canvas, Deelplan, true);
    }

        // Set some Buttons to visible:
    ToonESTWRegels(Vormgeving->SymboolGrootte == SG_ESTW && Vormgeving->ESTWButtons);

    Canvas->Unlock();   // release Canvas 
}
```

Comment: Do not manipulate the UI in an OnPaint event, only draw it. IOW, don't change the property values for the scrollbars, etc. That can trigger a repaint. And you don't need to Lock/Unlock the Form's Canvas at all

Comment: Hi Remy, thank you.
I changed the code so that setting the Scrollbars and positioning the buttons now take place in the OnShow event. That seems to help. Positioning the buttons in the window seems to be the main cause of the problem, but only when the window is above a certain size....